# Matlab - Dimensional mismatch

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have some homework on matlab functions.
The task is to make a function `acc=accvec(m,rv,rl)` which calculates the following:
[image].

Where `m` is a 3x1 array, `rv` is a 3x3x3 array and `rl` is a 3x3 array. My solution is the following:

```
function acc=accvec(m,rv,rl)
% calculate the acceleration of the object
s=size(rv);
acc=zeros(s(1),s(2));

global G

for i=1:s(2)
    for j=1:s(2)
        if i ~= j
            for k=1:3
                acc(k,i)=acc(k,i)-G*m(j)*rl(i,j)./rv(k,i,j)^3;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3drjcc7v93oqcbw/Stackoverflow.rar?dl=0) to a rar file which contains all the functions used . If you feed `rv` with `r=[1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]` and `rl` with the freshly calculated `rv` and make `m=[1 2 3]` and `G=1;` the result should be

```
acc = 
-1.7678    0.3536    0.3536
0.7071   -1.4142    0.7071
1.0607    1.0607   -1.0607
```

But my function `ac` throws a dimensional mismatch and I just can't figure out why and I'm in need of someone else looking at it and going oh it's so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this code isn't working is because `G` has not been initialized, even though you have made it `global`.  Referring to the [documentation on `global`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html), a variable is `global` only during the lifetime of a particular program.  Also, when a variable is `global`, all functions **within the lifetime of the script you are executing** will be able to see this variable.

Even though you are probably setting it to something outside of your function before you are calling it, `G` doesn't actually get set to anything.  Remember, when functions are called in MATLAB, the variables you declare are only defined within the scope of that function so any values you set outside of the function before you execute it will not be visible.  Therefore, you need to set this variable yourself inside the script.

If you manually change `G` so that it's set to 1 (as per your post), then you will be able to get an answer.  As such, do this instead:

```
G = 1;
```

Your program should now run.  I actually just did a test with random data and it outputs a 3 x 3 matrix.  However, the accuracy of the formula you are computing I haven't checked, so I'm going to leave that to you as an exercise.  Good luck!

Comment: Oh that's right. Now it runs. And I just found the error(I had flipped rv and rl). So now it produces the correct result. Thanks. The reason for the global variable was that we were to assume that G was defined as a global variable in the website that checks our code. My mistake. Thanks a lot!